# Setting the Attachment Owner as another User

Tags: apex, attachment, insufficient-privileges

I have a custom object with OWD set to private. I've created a record and have set the record owner to a user in the system. Now I'm attempting to add an attachment to this object with the owner as the record owner. **(record owner is different than logged in user)**

I get the following error:

> [INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY]

Can the attachment owner be set to another user by any logged in user? Or does the attachment owner have to be set as the logged in user?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Attachment object doesn't have separate OWD settings, and if an user has access to the Parent object then that user can access to Attachment record.

Secondly, when the attachment is created then OwnerId of the Attachment will always be creator of the attachment. This ownerId be either logged in user or any running user is creating an attachment.

You can update the OwnerId of attachment to any user who has access to the parent record.

Comment: The user I'm attempting to set as the attachment owner has Create/Read/Edit access on the parent object, so I believe they have sufficient rights. They've also been set as the record owner with no issues, just the attachment that doesn't seem to be going through.

Comment: Attachment owner should have access to the parent record. Don't confuse yourself with CRUD permission at profile level. The parent record must be shared to that user who will be the attachment owner. It that makes sense? Since you are using OWD as Private, so only Parent record owner and any users above the role hierarchy should have access to the Parent record. To provide the access to other users you have to write sharing rules.

Comment: ok yes, the user I'm attempting to assign as the attachment owner is the parent record owner and has FULL ACCESS to the parent record. I tested it on an update operation and it works. It gives me this error only on insert. Any ideas why?

Comment: Thanks for your help, we just left the attachment owner blank and we'll keep it as the createdby user.